# How to add an extra parameter in my callback function and call it from another file

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters, callback

I Have three files.

first, manager.js - This is where i have defined the function prevImage(a,b,c,d, callback)

second, connect.js - this calls the prevImage(callback)..

third, container.js - This is where i call the callback of the prevImage to get the image.

My function works fine and i am ble to call connect.js from container.js to get an image. Now i was to add another paramter into connect.js.

the code look like this:

manager.js:

```
mapmanager.GetPreviewImage = function(lo, la, lod, mplayerS, sc, callback) {
....
}
```

connect.js:

```
connect.prevImage = function(callback) {
        var layer = map.type;
        if(..) {
        } else {
        }
}
```

container.js - This has a popover which has items. my item has a press event. When the user presses on an item the item will have a name. i want this name to be passed to the connect.preview... to be used as the value for layer variable.

```
press: function(event) {
    stacks.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.name === text) {

        //this value needs to be passed to connect.js 
        //as the value for layer variable
        var mply = entry.name; 
        control.sc.connect.prevImage( function (img) {
                slctMap.setSrc(img.src);
        });
}
```

In the above i need to add a new parameter:

```
control.sc.connect.prevImage( function (mplayerS, img) {
    slctMap.setSrc(img.src);
});
```

and

```
connect.prevImage = function(mplayerS,Callback) {
            var layer = map.type;  //this here will be the value from container
            if(..) {
            } else {
            }
    }
```

The new parameter inside connect.js called 'mplayerS' should get its value from container.js variable 'layer'.

How an i add the new parameter to connect.js?

Answer (score 0):

One of the fantastic things about JavaScript is that it will just keep on plugging along regardless of what the programmer does a lot of times, this is also one of it's caveats. JavaScript doesn't require that you declare a variable to handle the data when you are passing it a parameter. This is where the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) array could come into play. You can pass a JS function any amount of parameters you wish and take in any amount using the arguments array, just watch out for null values.

Edit: 
The below snippet illustrates the use of callbacks and the argument array. I understand it's not your code which I did for two reasons; The first being that I can't implement your environment and the second being that I don't want to just give you the answer but would rather you think about this then ask questions about what's happening with the callbacks and arguments.

```js
var getPreviewImage = function(lo, la, lod, mplayerS, sc, callback) {
  console.log("In getPreviewImage");
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(lo);
}

var prevImage = function(mplayerS, callback) {
  callback(mplayerS);
}

var myCallback = function() {
  console.log("In myCallback");
  console.log(arguments);
}

function run() {
  prevImage("this is my player", myCallback);
  prevImage("this is my other player", getPreviewImage);
};

run();
```

Comment: Could you please help me using the code above :) than you.